# Show custom menu in category and its posts

Tags: categories, pages, sub-menu

I have a category X of posts. The category page and it's individual posts are all part of a custom menu consisting of pages and posts.

My submenu, in the sidebar, works fine for showing on the pages, but doesn't show up at all on the category page or any of its posts.

How can I get it to show up?

Answer (score 1):

*Posting answer found by the [OP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/19794/jamie), as originally [edited into the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/63514/3) and expanded on [in comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63514/show-custom-menu-in-category-and-its-posts#comment84905_63527):*

> Here is what I ended up doing, which works a charm. I put this in my `sidebar.php`. Basically, it works with the custom post type name to check that it's a single post with that type. If so, I tell it to append a list of all the pages that are children of Page ID 8.

```
<?php if( is_singular('menus')) { ?> 
  <nav role="inner"> 
    <ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=8'); ?></ul> 
  </nav> 
<?php } ?>
```

> Just for the record, I had to use another solution for a submenu that only existed in the Custom Menus. It works the same as the above solution but calls the `venue-menu` I registered in my `functions.php` and then defined in the custom menus section. `wp_nav_menu()` automatically outputs content in a `<ul>` so no need to add it in the HTML here:

```
<?php if( is_singular('venues'))  { ?>
  <nav role="inner">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array ("theme_location" => "venue-menu")) ?>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you are using theme that doesn't have custom menu supporting code inside `post` and `category` templates.
Since it's working fine in `page` template you should go to `Appearance -> Editor` and open for editing `page.php` or `index.php` and look for `wp_nav_menu()` with all it's arguments. Select and copy and insert it inside your `category` and `page` template.

That's the basic idea but it depends how your theme is implemented. If you provide me with more details I might help you more precisely.

Comment: hm.. maybe I just don't understand how the menu works. I am using custom menus which I defined in Appearance>Menus; it shows up fine on all pages but not posts, categories, etc. When I go in the index.php or page.php, I don't see wp_nav_menu() at all - I just see a sidebar include:

              <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

I am using the twentyeleven theme which I have been customizing.

Comment: I put the get_sidebar(); call into the single templates and no change.. any ideas?

Comment: you can edit `single.php` and add `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` then play with css to accommodate sidebar on post page. or just rename `single.php` to `single.bak` for Wordpress to display post using page template(which natively supports sidebar)

Comment: http://futurewebblog.com/add-sidebar-support-posts-twenty-eleven-theme/

Comment: here is what I ended up doing, which works a charm. I put this in my sidebar.php. Basically, it works with the custom post type name to check that it's a single post with that type. If so, I tell it to append a list of all the pages that are children of Page ID 8.


<?php if( is_singular('menus')) { ?>
   <nav role="inner">
     <ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=8'); ?></ul>
   </nav>
<?php } ?>

Comment: just for the record, I had to use another solution for a submenu that only existed in the Custom Menus. It works the same as the above solution but calls the venue-menu I registered in my functions.php and then defined in the custom menus section. wp_nav_menu automatically outputs content in a <ul> so no need to add it in the html here.

<?php if( is_singular('venues'))  { ?>
  <nav role="inner">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array ("theme_location" => "venue-menu")) ?>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>

Comment: cool jamie. glad you worked it out. hopefully i was of any help.